# App not installed in react native android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I build a react app using expo but i change it to react-native CLI . Now when I want to install the generated released-unsigned-apk the installation failed. I test this line of codes:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

but still I can't install the app. 
   Here is package.json content:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "postinstall": "jetify"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-native-unimodules": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "react-image-gallery": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-dropdownalert": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.11",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-image-slider-show": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-modals": "^0.19.9",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.5",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^6.3.3",
    "react-native-select-multiple": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.4",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-range-slider": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  },


"private": true
}
```

**UPDATE**
here is the logcat when run the react-native run-android

```
 02-11 16:00:21.802 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:21.802 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:22.812 7069-14035/? E/SPPClientService: [e] Push Channel Exception : java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
02-11 16:00:22.812 7069-14035/? E/SPPClientService: [e] exceptionCaught(). CONNECTION_RESET_BY_PEER

    --------- beginning of system
02-11 16:00:22.862 7069-7168/? E/SPPClientService: [b] SharedConstants.WHAT_PUSH_NETWORK_NOT_AVAILABLE
02-11 16:00:22.862 7069-7168/? E/SPPClientService: [b] ResponseMap empty
02-11 16:00:22.862 7069-14035/? E/SPPClientService: [a] onDisconnected Time : 3695898
02-11 16:00:22.872 7069-7069/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] reqType : 0
02-11 16:00:22.882 7069-7069/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] F:false, D:false, E:false, T:false, S:true, R:false
02-11 16:00:22.892 7069-7069/? E/SPPClientService: [a] [ConnectionManager] Connection is already disconnected.
02-11 16:00:23.032 3300-3344/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 11 size : 12Kb duration : 97ms lastUpdatedAfter : 11000 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 6622
02-11 16:00:23.642 7069-7168/? E/SPPClientService: [b] __InitReply__
02-11 16:00:23.662 7069-7168/? E/SPPClientService: [a] onConnected Time : 3696693
02-11 16:00:23.802 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:23.802 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:23.812 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:23.812 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:24.802 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:24.802 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:24.822 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:24.822 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:25.802 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:25.802 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:25.822 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:25.822 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:27.812 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:27.812 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:27.842 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:27.842 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:35.842 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:35.842 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:35.852 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:35.852 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:36.852 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:36.852 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:36.862 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:36.862 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:38.292 15343-15343/? E/Zygote: v2
02-11 16:00:38.292 15343-15343/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
02-11 16:00:38.632 15360-15360/? E/Zygote: v2
02-11 16:00:38.642 15360-15360/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
02-11 16:00:38.882 15360-15360/com.example.chitmall E/SensorManager: nativeGetSensorAtIndex: name, vendor - 0, K2HH Acceleration , STM
02-11 16:00:38.882 15360-15360/com.example.chitmall E/SensorManager: nativeGetSensorAtIndex: name, vendor - 1, STK3013 Proximity Sensor, SENSORTEK
02-11 16:00:38.882 15360-15360/com.example.chitmall E/SensorManager: nativeGetSensorAtIndex: name, vendor - 2, SX9310 Grip Sensor, SEMTECH
02-11 16:00:38.882 15360-15360/com.example.chitmall E/SensorManager: nativeGetSensorAtIndex: name, vendor - 3, Screen Orientation Sensor, Samsung Electronics
02-11 16:00:40.462 15442-15442/? E/Zygote: v2
02-11 16:00:40.462 15442-15442/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
02-11 16:00:40.472 15343-15422/? E/LauncherUtil: Failed to get system resource ID.
02-11 16:00:40.532 3490-3490/? E/HwDetectorWithState: a: 3
02-11 16:00:40.852 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:40.852 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:40.862 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:40.862 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:42.862 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:42.862 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:42.882 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:42.882 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:48.192 2581-3476/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 105 [02-11 16:00:48.202]
02-11 16:00:51.122 2313-2901/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
02-11 16:00:51.992 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: disableGripSensor, state = 1024
02-11 16:00:52.122 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: disableProxSensor, backoffstate = 1024
02-11 16:00:52.122 2581-2936/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1024
02-11 16:00:57.762 2313-2901/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
02-11 16:00:57.772 2581-2581/? E/Sensors: GripSensor: enable
02-11 16:00:57.862 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: GripVal = [0]
02-11 16:00:57.872 2581-2936/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1024
02-11 16:00:57.912 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:57.912 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:57.932 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:57.932 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:58.922 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:58.922 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:00:58.942 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:00:58.942 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 2
02-11 16:01:02.682 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:01:02.682 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:01:05.482 2581-2581/? E/Sensors: GripSensor: enable
02-11 16:01:07.752 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: disableGripSensor, state = 1024
02-11 16:01:07.842 2313-2901/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
02-11 16:01:07.882 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: disableProxSensor, backoffstate = 1024
02-11 16:01:07.882 2581-2936/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1024
02-11 16:01:08.522 3045-13674/? E/KeyguardViewMediator: lockAfterTimeout = 0 policyTimeout = 0
02-11 16:01:09.282 2581-2768/? E/PowerManagerService: handleSandman : startDreaming, but isDreaming false
02-11 16:01:09.292 3045-3045/? E/KeyguardViewMediator: setShowingLocked mShowing = true
02-11 16:01:09.322 2581-2932/? E/MotionRecognitionService:  handler : SCREEN_OFF end 
02-11 16:01:09.342 3622-3635/? E/ucsBai_agentService: notifyChange NOT SUPPORTED
02-11 16:01:09.362 2581-2991/? E/WifiNative-wlan0: do suspend true
02-11 16:01:09.412 3045-3045/? E/LSO: LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
02-11 16:01:09.482 2581-3200/? E/SdpServiceKeeper: isLicensed {pid:3045 uid:10047 userid:0 doPkg:null}
02-11 16:01:09.482 2581-3200/? E/SdpServiceKeeper: System app. Skip license activation
02-11 16:01:09.482 2581-3181/? E/SdpServiceKeeper: isLicensed {pid:3045 uid:10047 userid:0 doPkg:null}
02-11 16:01:09.482 2581-3181/? E/SdpServiceKeeper: System app. Skip license activation
02-11 16:01:09.492 2581-4018/? E/SDP.CRYPTO:     On Locked OK, id 0
02-11 16:01:09.492 2581-4018/? E/SdpManagerService: sendBroadcastAsUser(INTENT_SDP_STATE_CHANGED, state:1)
02-11 16:01:09.632 3887-4163/? E/BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler: com.samsung.android.beaconmanager, msg: MESSAGE_STOP_SCAN
02-11 16:01:09.642 9828-9828/? E/SamsungIME: invoke(): method is null
02-11 16:01:09.662 15343-15425/? E/WorkerLoader: No worker found for Worker ID [trainingcache].
02-11 16:01:10.552 2581-2581/? E/Sensors: GripSensor: enable
02-11 16:01:10.612 2313-2901/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
02-11 16:01:10.642 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: GripVal = [0]
02-11 16:01:10.642 2581-2936/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1024
02-11 16:01:15.522 2581-2581/? E/Sensors: GripSensor: enable
02-11 16:01:18.202 2581-3476/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 106 [02-11 16:01:18.203]
02-11 16:01:23.192 3300-3344/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 11 size : 12Kb duration : 150ms lastUpdatedAfter : 60164 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 6622
02-11 16:01:32.822 2313-2901/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
02-11 16:01:33.552 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: disableGripSensor, state = 1024
02-11 16:01:33.682 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: disableProxSensor, backoffstate = 1024
02-11 16:01:33.682 2581-2936/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1024
02-11 16:01:42.642 2313-2901/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
02-11 16:01:42.722 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:01:42.722 3045-3045/? E/SignalClusterView: setSlotFocusVisible : subId 1
02-11 16:01:42.782 2581-2581/? E/Sensors: GripSensor: enable
02-11 16:01:42.882 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: GripVal = [0]
02-11 16:01:42.882 2581-2936/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1024
02-11 16:01:45.672 2581-2581/? E/Sensors: GripSensor: enable
02-11 16:01:45.672 4202-4202/? E/MtpServerJNI: server is null in send_object_removed
02-11 16:01:48.202 2581-3476/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 107 [02-11 16:01:48.204]
02-11 16:01:58.622 2313-2901/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
02-11 16:01:58.802 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: disableGripSensor, state = 1024
02-11 16:01:58.932 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: disableProxSensor, backoffstate = 1024
02-11 16:01:58.932 2581-2936/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1024
02-11 16:02:09.452 2581-2581/? E/Sensors: GripSensor: enable
02-11 16:02:09.512 2313-2901/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
02-11 16:02:09.552 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: GripVal = [0]
02-11 16:02:09.552 2581-2936/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1024
02-11 16:02:15.722 2581-2581/? E/Sensors: GripSensor: enable
02-11 16:02:18.202 2581-3476/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 108 [02-11 16:02:18.205]
02-11 16:02:19.432 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: disableGripSensor, state = 1024
02-11 16:02:19.562 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: disableProxSensor, backoffstate = 1024
02-11 16:02:19.562 2581-2936/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1024
02-11 16:02:19.842 2313-2901/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
02-11 16:02:23.322 3300-3344/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 11 size : 12Kb duration : 135ms lastUpdatedAfter : 60123 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 6622
02-11 16:02:23.522 2581-2581/? E/Sensors: GripSensor: enable
02-11 16:02:23.582 2313-2901/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
02-11 16:02:23.622 2581-2581/? E/MotionRecognitionService: GripVal = [0]
02-11 16:02:23.622 2581-2936/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1024
02-11 16:02:25.762 2581-2581/? E/Sensors: GripSensor: enable
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: what is the error or what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: @GauravRoy App not installed

Comment: can u share image of your android folder with res and drawable folder expanded?

Comment: @Ajeett I am trying your solution. I delete all images in drawable directories. The project is building ...

Comment: I don't know the true solution. but i making new project without expo library solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

So you are checking it for Android right? After you run the bundle command which is

```
 react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

You will notice that some unwanted images are created in your Android>res>drawable folder. You need to remove those image files and then recreate a Signed Apk.

Comment: I do this but still got the app not installed message

Comment: have you removed all the images that were created during bundling like from folders drawable, drawable h-dpi, etc.?

Comment: Yes i have delete all images in all drawable directories

Comment: Try creating a debug apk and run it. Also, check the log cat for any errors

Comment: Same problem for debug version. I just can run app with react-native run-android

Comment: Okay then run app using  react-native run-android and then check for logcat we will get the main cause of error there

Comment: i have updated my question (logcat is added). thanks